# why all exception is being catched by ldap.SERVER_DOWN?

Tags: python, exception, ldap

i have some code like below, i am trying to connect a server which is not existed to test timeout. after 120 sec, program quits with code 5. and more, i disconnect from lan to test connect_error and it exits with code 5 again. why all exception is being catched by ldap.SERVER_DOWN? how can i test other exceptions?

```
try:
    ....

    l.simple_bind_s(user, password)

except ldap.CONNECT_ERROR, e:
    sys.exit(1)

except ldap.BUSY, e:
    sys.exit(2)

except ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, e:
    sys.exit(3)

except ldap.TIMEOUT, e: 
    sys.exit(4)

except ldap.SERVER_DOWN, e:
    sys.exit(5)
```

Comment: what is e? I think it should have 'as' keyword if it is the exception object

Comment: @Darhazer: `as` and `,` [are synonyms](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#except), but `as` is new to Python 2.6.

Comment: Also, the comma goes away in Python 3 and `as` must be used.  See PEP 3110 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/.

Comment: guys please focus on my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the python-ldap source, it looks like only a `NonblockingLDAPObject` can raise the exception `ldap.TIMEOUT`.  You shouldn't have to handle it for a `SimpleLDAPObject`.

Answer (score 0):

To test for BUSY you could bind to a working LDAP server, and then don't close (unbind) the connection. When you try and connect again the server should throw the BUSY error.